# How do I get the values from the counter after I processed all the records with Google AppEngine MapReduce?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

How do I get the values from the counter after I processed all the records with Google AppEngine MapReduce?

Or am I missing the use case for counters here?

**Sample Code from http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/UserGuidePython**

How would I retrieve the value of counter **counter1** when the mapreduce is done?

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce/main.py
  login: admin
```

**mapreduce/main.py**

```
from mapreduce import operation as op
def process(entity):
    yield op.counters.Increment("counter1")
```

**mapreduce.yaml**

```
mapreduce:
- name: <Some descriptive name for UI>
  mapper:
    input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader
    handler: main.process
    params:
    - name: entity_kind
      default: <your entity name, e.g. main.MyEntity>
```

Comment: to add to manjoor's comment, it would help if you posted some sample code, or at the very least mentioned if you are using java or python :)

Comment: Ok. I've added the example code from the Google Code Wiki.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the python version of Google App Engine mapreduce, how do you access counters from the done_callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011582/in-the-python-version-of-google-app-engine-mapreduce-how-do-you-access-counters)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137485/how-can-i-access-the-mapper-reducer-counters-on-the-output-stage

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Since you're posting the code from the docs I'll assume you haven't tried to run a mapper yet.  The results from the counter should show up on the admin page for the mapreduce session.  There must be a way to access the values from within the mapper as well but I am not familiar enough with the Python version of the API to tell you how.  I know it is doable in the Java side.

Comment: That interesting. Is the sum of a counter, the sum of the counters in all mappers? That would mean that the counters are reduced!?