# In the python version of Google App Engine mapreduce, how do you access counters from the done_callback?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am using Google App Engine mapreduce to analyze some data. I am generating a few counters that I would like to create a simple Google chart from in my done_callback. How do I access the resulting counters from the callback?

```
#The map method
def count_created_since(entity):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  delta = now-entity.created

  #analyze last 12 weeks
  for x in range(12):
    start = 7*x
    stop = 7*(x+1)

    if delta.days >= start and delta.days < stop:
      #The counters
      yield op.counters.Increment(str(x)+" weeks ago")


def my_callback(request):
  # fetch counter results to create a simple Google chart url
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the counter's through a [`MapreduceState`'s](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/model.py#490) `counter_map` attribute.

```
from mapreduce import model
state = model.MapreduceState.get_by_job_id(your_job_id)
# counters live in state.counters_map
```

There was a [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f5e2486e9fca0277/c1fa19a100eb9a18) on the mailing list a month or so ago about accessing counters.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I determine the job_id in the callback? Is it passed in as parameter via the POST to the callback?

Comment: It is passed in as a parameter named `job_id`.

Comment: @Chris @Robert, I don't know how it was passed when you answer this question but today it is passed in the header in a variable called **Mapreduce-Id**