# Having difficulty in mapreduce to understand

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I have seen the below link which is of getting started mapreduce with python

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython

But still I am not able to understand how its working. I am executing below code but not able to understand what exactly is happening?

**mapreduce.yaml**

```
mapreduce: 
- name: Testmapper 
   mapper: 
       input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader 
       handler: main.process 
   params: 
       - name: entity_kind 
         default: main.userDetail
```

**mapreduce/main.py**

```
some code

class userDetail(db.Model): 
name = db.StringProperty()

some code

def process(u): 
          u.name="mahesh" 
          yield op.db.Put(u)
```

I am executing this and it gives me status = success in status page.

But not able to understand what happend

The main thing I want do with mapreduce is to search or count records from entity

So anyone can please help me??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could format code by indenting 4 spaces. No need to insert a bunch of `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `"mahesh"` value to the `StringProperty name` of all your `userDetail` entities.

If you want to count your entities use :

```
from mapreduce import operation as op
 def process(entity):
    yield op.counters.Increment("counter1")
```

Comment: the code that u given is working fine for counters but my question was where this record is being stored?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465669/how-do-i-get-the-values-from-the-counter-after-i-processed-all-the-records-with-g